# jQuery click() function doesn't work in FireFox in my linux machine but works in windows

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to web development, and trying to get the browse button clicked in my HTML page as soon as my webpage loads. To achieve that, i have done this : onload="activate()" inside body tag.

This is my javascript code:

```
<script>
    function activate() {
    $("input#selectFiles").click();
}
</script>
```

Note that, **selectFiles** is the id of input tag in HTML here. Now, it works fine and as soon as the page loads in Firefox in my windows OS, the browse button is clicked and a page opens for selecting files. The same code i tried opening in Firefox in Linux from terminal, the button is not clicked at all. However, i checked that the function activate() is being called but .click() is not working. What can be the possible reason for this ? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it because of the difference in versions of Firefox that i am using in windows or Linux.  Just for information:   In my windows OS, Firefox version that I am using is 64.0 but in Linux it's 38.0.1 .

Comment: can you share your firefox version on both os? what is your jquery version?

Comment: I am using jquery 3.3.1

Comment: Upgrade firefox version on Linux and it should work.

Comment: I got my Firefox updated and now it works as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

first you should try to update your Firefox browser

Or

remove `onload="activate()"`

> The problem is caused by another jquery background plugin which is
>   placed inside $(document).ready()
>
> I moved it inside $(window).load() function, now it works perfect.
>
> I have also moved another function to resize images on the page load.
>   When it was inside $(document).ready() block, sometimes it was
>   malfunctioning if loading time took too long but now it also works
>   great.

use the following code for all browser

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input#selectFiles").click(function(){
    alert("now working fine");
  });

});
```

it work same as you want
i hope it work for you

thanks.

Comment: I tried this. It's not working. I think this is the problem with the Firefox version that I am using in my Linux OS.

Comment: may be or may be not. please check is there any error in console or not.

Comment: I got my Firefox updated and now it works as expected. Thanks